# can't load a docker image in windows server 2016

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerhub, windows-server-2016, docker-image

I'm trying to load an image on my Windows Server 2016. But for some reason I'm unable to do so. I have tried several things. Including:

Saving an image, copy pasting it to the server and trying to load it (docker load...). This gives the error you see down below. I also tried to load the image through docker hub. But using docker pull gives me the exact same error.

I've tried pulling other images like microsoft/windowsservercore which was successful. On my development machine and server I'm using windows containers. The windows server runs in a virtual machine.

I've created a sample project on https://hub.docker.com/r/sbrauer/dockert/.
This project is just a asp.netcore web api project with the default 'valuescontroller' as a test. But this gave me the same error.

I have to say that pulling the image to my dev machine (w10) works perfectly fine. I tried to load the image on the server using docker CE and using docker EE but both to no avail.

error code:

```
failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: 
ProcessUtilityVMImage C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilte
r\13f0d09f57da5375955d3563b3a199fd1f3563365abe5b31640eee885aac448a\UtilityVM: 
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Please add more details about your custom image, how you built it, what's inside, that sort of stuff, then come back and edit your post to be straight to the point.